# looking for an explicit expression for an integral

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to solve EDP through my computations I have found the following indefinite integral $\int (1+x^2)^{-2/3}\,dx$.
Is there any way to write this expression explicitly?

Comment: it's a hypergeometric function, so it's explicit but not an elementary function: $\int(1+x^2)^{-2/3}\,dx=x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{3}{2};-x^2\right)$

Comment: See [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/715715/13130) and [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3820143/13130) for details about the evaluation of integrals of the form $\int x^m \left(ax^n + b\right)^{p} \, dx.$ Your integral corresponds to $m=0$ and $a=b=1$ and $n=2$ and $p=-2/3.$

Comment: Carlo Beenakker and Dave L Renfro your answers are very helpful, thanks!